# Cannot Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with EB Single Instance NodeJS NGINX Config

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been struggling all week trying to get http to https redirect working with elastic beanstalk's default single instance setup for nodejs while **not** behind a load balancer. I've created a .ebextensions/https-instance.config file (below) to setup https successfully and at the top have the port 80 redirect but it is not being recognized. The site still allows http.

Is there no way to do this redirect with the .ebextensions? Do I really have to ssh into the server and get the existing config file and then override the whole thing as shown here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html?

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/http_custom_proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        listen 80;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/https.conf:
     ...already working https code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl_rewrite.conf":
   mode: "000644"
   owner: ec2-user
   group: ec2-user
   content: |
       TraceEnable off
       RewriteEngine On
       <If "-n '%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}' && %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} != 'https'">
       RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
       </If>
```

Comment: It's a single instance environment, no load balancer. The `X-Forwarded-Proto` header is added by a load balancer. So this solution won't work in this case.

Comment: I gave it a whirl but this did not work, probably because not being behind a load balancer as @MarkB mentioned. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @SeanMerron yes, sorry. When I saw https, I assumed you were using a load balancer. Now that I reread the OP, I see it says “single instance”

Answer (score -2):

For https, you should redirect to 443 port. that might be the problem

Comment: By specifying the `https` protocol without specifying a port, they are automatically specifying the default HTTPS port of `443`.